# How to limit your ASP.NET Web API audience to a single app, no login required?

Tags: asp.net, azure, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I am currently building an ASP.NET Web API which unique purpose is to provide data to a Windows Phone app. I already finished the Web API development and I published it in an Azure website for testing purpose.

It works like a charm but my issue now is that this Web API is now publicly accessible. What I would like is to find the simplest way to limit the audience to my particular Windows Phone app and nobody else. I first thought of using an API key but it does not seem that ASP.NET proposes this as a builtin option. The builtin options are not satisfying either because their require a login.

Basically I want that only my Windows Phone app can access the Web API and that this authorization is transparent for the user (no authentication required). Any suggestions?

PS: The Web API is deployed on Azure, will not be distributed to other developers and securing with HTTPS is a possibility.

---

I did an implementation and blogged about it : http://www.ucodia.fr/blog/simple-authorization-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're looking for a very basic, stop the casual hacker method, there is a simple technique that can be used with the Web API and [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)s. As there are two identically named attribute classes with that name, make sure you're `using` the one from `System.Web.Http.Filters`.

It would be very common to send a token of some sort, that would either be generated, or encoded permanently into the application. So, in this example, a header value would be encoded into every request, and then checked using the filter.

```
[VerifyToken]
public class MyAPI : ApiController
{

}

public class VerifyTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        // get the token from wherever you'd like ...
        var token = filterContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Token").First();
        if (token != GetCurrentToken())
        {
            filterContext.Response = 
                new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what looks like the "API key" scenario which seems pretty easy to implement to me. Only question is, does that means that I would have to secure the wire with HTTPS so the header would encrypted and hide the token?

Comment: I'd always recommend HTTPS anytime you're sending data that needs to be secured.

Comment: The data is actually nothing but confidential. Only the token needs to be hidden.

Comment: There's really no place to "hide" a token (or anything) in an HTTP request. The best you can get is encrypting it ... but then there's the issue of are you using the same encryption key (because if you are, then someone doesn't need it, they'll just send it). If you're using an algorithm that generates tokens based on time-of-day for example, then there's less to protect overall, but there could still be the issue of a compromised key for a period .... It's really up to you.

Comment: Ultimately, it just is key management and how many layers of obfuscation you introduce into the system. If the server provides the seed, then any client could fetch the seed.  You could use a public/private key and exchange tokens that way too.

Comment: I am targeting mobile platforms, potentially thousands of devices, and therefore I can't expect all clients to be on time. But perhaps, maybe my server could publicly provide a seed that would server to token generation on client side? Do you think that could work? (Sorry I deleted my comment while you were commenting back...)

Comment: So I finally decided that I will keep it simple by combining a hardcoded token with HTTPS and an IAuthorizationFilter implementation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be truly secure? or just secure enough?

For 'secure enough', I will usually just use an API key as you suggest that the client app passes to the back-end and for which the back-end will not respond if the key doesn't match. This will provide a very basic level of security to prevent someone who just happens along from executing arbitrary api calls; for read only, non-confidential data this has usually been enough for me.

For a bit of added level of security you could you a rotating time-sensitive api key that changes based on the time of the day (with perhaps a sliding window to account for minor clock differences between clients and server). This ups the security by obscurity just a bit more, requiring someone to do a bit more work before they crack your code.

Depending on your app, it might also be a good idea to consider rate throttling your API responses as well, if there is a discernible max number of calls any given client should make to your API, you could geometrically slow down the responses to thwart attempts at misuse if someone does bypass your security.

Comment: Fortunately the API only provides data publicly available on the web so no need for extra hard security. I do like the idea of creating a personalized algorithm for generating keys but if it is based on day and time it has an extra requirement that the client phone is on time. Your reply is pretty similar to the other one that has been posted before but +1 for rotating key and throtlling.